# menu created by ul and fill the second level

Tags: html, css

This is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/lighter/pen/bvgYod).

I used `ul` to create a menu. This is my html code.

```js
$('.navbar').find('.active').show();

$('.a-node').on('click', function() {
  $('.active').removeClass('active').hide();
  $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('active').show();
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  width: 200px;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0pt;
}

.navbar>ul>li ul {
  display: none;
}

.navbar ul li {
  background: #eeeeee;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  width: 89%;
  padding: 5% 0 5% 10%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9d9d9d;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  background: red;
}

.ul-level2 li {
  margin-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
  <ul class="ul-level1">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="a-node">1</a>
      <ul class="ul-level2 active">
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="a-node">2</a>
      <ul class="ul-level2">
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want the second level's under line and hover color same as first level.

Result is this.

[image]

And I want this.

[image]

Thanks your help.

Comment: This should help you https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Comment: @VXp I modified my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css to your code

```
.ul-level2 li:hover {
      background: red;
}
```

Also, change `margin-left: 20%` into `padding-left: 20%` in following code

```
.ul-level2 li  {
      margin-left: 20%; // Change this into padding-left: 20%
 }
```

Following is the working snippet

```js
$('.navbar').find('.active').show();

$('.a-node').on('click', function() {
  $('.active').removeClass('active').hide();
  $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('active').show();
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  width: 200px;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0pt;
}

.navbar > ul > li ul {
  display: none;
}

.navbar ul li {
  background: #eeeeee;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  width: 89%;
  padding: 5% 0 5% 10%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9d9d9d;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  background: red;
}

.ul-level2 li  {
  padding-left: 20%;
}

.ul-level2 li:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
  <ul class="ul-level1">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="a-node">1</a>
      <ul class="ul-level2 active">
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="a-node">2</a>
      <ul class="ul-level2">
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: But how can I fill the second level under line as same as first level?

Comment: You can add border-bottom property into second level li.

Comment: I got it. Thanks your help.